# Tower PC no longer connects to TV via HDMI cable

Tags: hdmi, tv

I have a PC connected to a TV via HDMI. It was working just fine until one day I turned both on and it wouldn't give me a signal. The problem is with the PC but I haven't managed to diagnose it. I know the following:

- I get no signal plugging the PC into either of the two HDMI ports - it only accepts HDMI
- The TV and cable are fine. They work with other computers plugged into the same HDMI ports
- The computer turns on and runs just fine when plugged into a monitor via VGA

Does anyone have any idea what else I can do?

Edit for more info:

The system that stopped working has the following specs:

- Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1
- Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5400 @ 2.70GHz
- RAM: 5.00 GB
- 64-bit operating system

The other is a Zotac also running Windows 7 Professional (That's all the specs I have on it at the moment)

Comment: Onboard video or another card? I have a discrete card that has issues with HDMI out but not VGA, and trying a (cheap) discrete card might be a good troubleshooting step

Comment: If its onboard HDMI it won't work if you plugged another vga card.

Comment: The problem is finally fixed but I don't understand why. Plugged into the other monitor it booted onto a screen warning me the memory file it had saved to HD during sleep mode could not be properly recovered. I restarted normally a couple of times and defragmented my main drive until it stopped yelling at me about the paging file being too small, but it worked when I set it back up on the other monitor. I don't know why it would would display the boot error message on the VGA monitor but the HDMI TV...